# Importing java class in domino java agent but want to change code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lotus-domino

I have created the following java class (called JavaAgent.java) in Eclipse (standalone IDE):

```
package com.ibm.NotesJava.agents;

import lotus.domino.AgentBase;
import lotus.domino.AgentContext;
import lotus.domino.Session;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

          try {

              Session session = getSession();
              AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
              System.out.println("tedadsadsast");
              // (Your code goes here)

          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

}
```

In IBM Domino, I created a new agent and imported a new java source and imported this java class. Then I changed package name to com.ibm.NotesJava.agents.

I can now see the java class and the code, but if I now change the code in eclipse then I dont see any changes in the same java class which I imported in to the agent.. How can I make the one in my java agent dependent on the changes in eclipse?